# copy files to sdcard before executing instrumentation tests

Tags: android, tdd, android-instrumentation

what's the best approach to copy data to sdcard before all instrumentation tests.
So far, my idea is to create Gradle task to do that. Do you have an idea how to do it more robust and simple?

Comment: Put the data on a server, and have `@BeforeClass` download them. IOW, put the data somewhere that the instrumentation test code can reach and copy into position.

Comment: what kind of data do you have to store i.e image, texts, alphanumeric etc

Comment: @CommonsWare I like your solution, it is easier to debug than doing it as a gradle task. However, with BeforeClass it will be executed anyway every single time when my tests will be executed in different classes. Can I somehow execute it only once?

Comment: @PratikVyas db and images

Comment: Most likely there is a JUnit recipe for that, though I do not know what it is off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar with a gradle task :

```
//Copy file form device to project
task copyFileForTest{
    group = "My_tasks"
    description ="Copy auth token from device to project"
    doFirst {
        println 'Getting file for Unit tests'
        def resFolder = new File(projectDir.absolutePath+'/src/test/res')
        exec {
            commandLine android.getAdbExecutable(),'pull', '-a', '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.myproject.debug/files/file.txt', "${resFolder.absolutePath}"
        }
    }
}
```

And then to be sure it will run after my instrumentation test:

```
copyFileForTest.mustRunAfter 'connectedAndroidTest'
```